# How can I create token using stripejs and reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, token, create-react-app

I want to create a token with `ReactJS` and stripe, I implemented the `formCard` :

```
export default class sForm extends React.Component {

 handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (this.props.stripe) {
      this.props.stripe
        .createToken()
        .then((payload) => console.log('[token]', payload));
    } else {
      console.log('Form submitted before Stripe.js loaded.');
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>Card details</label>

          <CardElement
          />

        <button disabled={!this.props.stripe}>Pay</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

and my Elements

```
const stripePromise = loadStripe('pk_test_IqIuWVA2XNYPVx03KrFUNxNB00hMZkyNQt');

 <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>                              
     <ElementsConsumer>
     {({stripe, elements}) => (
      <SForm stripe={stripe} elements={elements} />)}
  </ElementsConsumer></Elements>
```

When I run it I get :
[image]

How can I fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error message implies, you have to provide a Stripe Element when creating the token [0]. Assuming you are using the new React library ([@stripe/react-stripe-js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react)), you would do this by importing the `useElements` hook to get an elements instance, and then call the `getElement` method. For example:

```
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

export const sForm = () => {
 const stripe = useStripe();
 const elements = useElements();

 const handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    const cardElement = elements.getElement("card");

    stripe.createToken(cardElement)
      .then((payload) => console.log('[token]', payload));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <label>Card details</label>
       <CardElement />
       <button disabled={!stripe}>Pay</button>
    </form>
  );

}
```

I've prepped a full working example that you can reference here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-react-stripe-js-starting-point-h10v9

The relevant code is under `components/CheckoutForm.jsx`.

I hope this helps!

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement#stripe_create_token-tokenType

Comment: This is a little bit of an old thread, in the coding link you posted, where are you using the Stripe publishing key, as I understand is required to generate the token?

Answer (score 0):

Just change these lines.

```
const card = elements.getElement(CardElement)
const { token, error } = await stripe.createToken(card)
```